# How to differentiate Created and Modified in a workflow

Tags: list, workflow

I'm working on a workflow that needs to perform one action if the List item is being created for the first time and another if it's being updated.

How do I say:

```
If created - do this
else if modified - do this
```

I tried using `Association: Start on item change/creation` but it still takes the Created branch each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do If Created equals Modified do these actions Else do these actions.

When an item is created, it has the same date for created and modified. Once an item is modified, they have different dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without having to run any conditionals in your workflow.

Create two workflows (one for item creation, one for item change) and go to the workflow settings for each one.  Check `Start workflow automatically when an item is created` or `Start workflow automatically when an item is changed`.